# Error con función json_encode en php, no aparecen las comas

Tags: php, mysql, json

feliz navidad a todos antes que nada, tengo un problema.
Tengo el siguiente archivo.

```
<?php

header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

require_once '../core/db.php';
require_once '../core/modelo.php';

$obj = new modelo();

$data = $obj->listar_usuarios();

foreach($data as $i){

   echo json_encode($i,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

}
```

pero los elementos del array no me está separando con las comas, me aparecen asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

no se a que se deba

Comment: No aparecen porque estás haciendo echo de cada elemento, cuando basta con **echo json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);** sin foreach.

Comment: Asi lo tenia en un principio, pero no me aparece la información, pero si le hago un var_dump a la $data, si aparece información.

Comment: El único problema posible sería que tengas datos en codificación diferente de utf8, que es la que usa json_encode().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como bien dice **@Triby**, estás generando un JSON independiente en cada bucle del foreach y lo estás printando. Por tanto es normal que no te añada las comas.

Elimina el foreach y haz un `json_encode($data)` del array y listo.

Comment: Como le respondi a Triby, assi lo tenia en un principio, pero no me aparece la información, pero si le hago un var_dump a la $data, si aparece información.

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir a tu pregunta que te muestra cuando haces un `var_dump`? A ver si con eso vemos algo que se nos escapa! :)

Comment: https://prnt.sc/qg7fku <- aqui esta

Comment: Por lo que veo es un array bastante grande, y si algún dato no estuviera bien o las strings no tuvieran una codificación utf8 podría fallar en encode. Prueba a lanzar `json_last_error()` justo despues del `json_encode`. [json_last_error()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-last-error.php) debería devolverte el tipo de error al hacer el encode.

Comment: ya lo hice me aparece 5

Comment: Da la sensación que tienes caracteres con una codificación distinta a utf8. Echale un vistazo a [esta respuesta de stackoverflow en ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10199017/how-to-solve-json-error-utf8-error-in-php-json-decode#answer-26760943). Puede que te sirva de ayuda!

Comment: Es correcto, verifique y aparece el signo de � en algunos elementos, le coloque un LIMIT a la consulta, para que no cargue todos  y me aparece el json correctamente: https://prnt.sc/qg7qv7. Ahora tengo que arreglar la codificación. GRACIAS!